# Any difference between MD5 and SHA1 for getting MAP API?

Tags: google-maps, md5, sha1

I am getting following results:

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin>keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystor
e "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator.android\debug.keystore" -storepass a
ndroid -keypass android
androiddebugkey, May 27, 2011, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): "Some Code"

But after entering this in http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html for getting MAP API it is showing invalid fingerprint.

Can you please guide me is the fingerprint I have got is correct or not. Because I am getting it as SHA1 and not MD5. How can I get API key??

Answer (score 8):

keytool -v -list -alias alias_name -keystore my-release-key.keystore

With JDK 1.7 installed, keytool outputs by default SHA1 fingerprint, not MD5. Adding -v option allows to see MD5 as well.

Please update the page with this info, many devs are having problems trying to get a maps key.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19035

Answer (score 0):

After entering key add ; and your application package name
eg. sha1 code blablabla;com.example and then generate the key.

Happy coding....

also check [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-working-with-google-maps-application-setup/) tutorial and recheck steps you followed it worked for me....