# google maps api for android registration page

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm facing an issue with the google maps api for android.

All tutorials and instructions tell you to fetch that    debug.keystore file and fetch it's signature, and stick it into the google registration page.

This is failing for me, I'm getting this error

```
The fingerprint you entered is not valid. Please press the Back button on your browser and enter a valid certificate fingerprint.
```

I honestly have no idea what I'm doing wrong :( any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: here's the signature I'm getting

```
51:A6:89:45:CB:20:19:DF:55:CB:AE:23:E7:31:47:42:05:47:A2:79
```

I'm suspecting this is too long

Comment: The answer below is correct and worked for me after I found this post by googling the same issue...you should mark it as accepted so that future visitors will know that it is correct

Answer (score 8):

Did you follow instructions in section titled: Getting the MD5 Fingerprint of the SDK Debug Certificate found here:

http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html#overview

Do you have jdk 1.7?  I googled and found the following stackoverflow answer which I cannot verify since I do not have 1.7:
[Any difference between MD5 and SHA1 for getting MAP API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306473/any-difference-between-md5-and-sha1-for-getting-map-api)

which points to http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19035

and says "With JDK 1.7 installed, keytool outputs by default SHA1 fingerprint, not MD5. Adding -v option allows to see MD5 as well."

Comment: Yes sir, I did, th signature above is the one I got

Comment: When I tried with jre6 i got same error as mentioned in the question but when I tried with jre7 it worked fine.