# Debug keystore won't work

Tags: java, android, keystore

I'm trying to use my debug keystore so I can get a key for a map view, but when I try and use it, it comes up with this

```
Illegal option:  B:\Fabian\.android\debug.keystore
keytool -list [OPTION]...
```

Im ussing this:

```
keytool -v -list -keystore "C:\Users\MyPcName.android\debug.keystore"
```

---

When I try to use:

```
keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey \ -keystore <path_to_debug_keystore>.keystore \ -storepass android -keypass android
```

it comes up with

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin>keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey \ -k
ystore B:\Fabian\.android\.keystore \ -storepass android -keypass android
Illegal option:  \
keytool -list [OPTION]...

Lists entries in a keystore

Options:

 -rfc                            output in RFC style
 -alias <alias>                  alias name of the entry to process
 -keystore <keystore>            keystore name
 -storepass <arg>                keystore password
 -storetype <storetype>          keystore type
 -providername <providername>    provider name
 -providerclass <providerclass>  provider class name
 -providerarg <arg>              provider argument
 -providerpath <pathlist>        provider classpath
 -v                              verbose output
 -protected                      password through protected mechanism

Use "keytool -help" for all available commands
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is actually what you have to use to get a map api key :

`$ keytool -v -list -alias androiddebugkey \
-keystore <path_to_debug_keystore>.keystore \
-storepass android -keypass android`

Here you can find a lot information about this. It's working for me : [get Google Maps Api KEy](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey)

**EDIT:**
On Windows using command prompt go to this folder :

`C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin`

and type the code above. It should generate you a key which you have to paste here : [GET API KEY](https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup)

Comment: That doesnt seem to work, I was going of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997348/cant-find-the-android-keytool

Comment: First of all which OS you are trying to do this Mac/Windows/Linux?

Comment: I think that this line `B:\Fabian\.android\.keystore`  should looks like `B:\Fabian\.android\debug.keystore`, am I right?

Comment: don't believe so, I have the keystore now, removed the "\" from it between the commands like before -keystore, but now google isnt accepting it

Comment: "The fingerprint you entered is not valid. Please press the Back button on your browser and enter a valid certificate fingerprint."

Comment: Look if there are any white spaces before the first letter. You may be copied one extra white space from command prompt.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306473/any-difference-between-md5-and-sha1-for-getting-map-api

Comment: was generating sha1 not md5 adding -v gives you md5

Answer (score 6):

Try giving `keytool path` from `gre`. It worked for me.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\Jre7\bin>keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore
 "C:\Uers\Akki\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android
```

If you have installed Jdk 1.7 it will generate SHA1 key which will not work
for that use -v

C:\Program Files\Java\Jre7\bin>keytool -v -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore
     "C:\Uers\Akki.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android

Comment: thanks, you are right, for some reason it works with the JRE instead of the JDK, I am using JDK version 1_8_92

Answer (score 1):

> my debug keystore so I can get a key for a map view

First of all is it `(C:\Users\MyPcName.android\debug.keystore)` your app keystore?

And check your `keytool` path.

```
keytool -v -list -alias YOURAPPaliasName -keystore "here your keystore path"
```

- [See This Example](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-map-api-key.html)

Answer (score 0):

here is what worked for me, my command prompt at jre bin folder :

```
c:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\bin>keytool.exe -v -list -alias androiddebugkey  -keystore c:\Users\<UserDirectory>\.android\debug.keystore  -storepass android -keypass android
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.

> **Run this code in command prompt** (Replace <*enterYourPcUsername*> with your PC name)

```
keytool -v -list -alias androiddebugkey  -keystore c:\Users\<enterYourPcUsername>\.android\debug.keystore  -storepass android -keypass android
```